# ¿Cómo crear un directorio con un JOptionPane?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Quiero leer el texto que ingreso en el `JOptionPane` para crear una carpeta.

Ejemplo: Si hago lo siguiente me resulta utilizando un `JTextField`:

```
carpeta=new File(ruta,JTextField.getText());
```

Código:

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class VentanaProyecto extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    File ruta=new File("/Users/brianreyes/FBD/");
    File carpeta;
    File archivo;

    String opp;

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {                                 
        opp = (javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el nombre de la bd"));

        archivo= new File(ruta,"BASES.db");    
        carpeta=new File(ruta,opp); //Es en esta parte donde no me permite crearlo.
        //Dentro de la ruta.
        try {
            if (!carpeta.exists())
            {
                carpeta.mkdir();   
            }
            else if(carpeta.exists())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La carpeta ya existe.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        if(!archivo.exists())
        {
            try{archivo.createNewFile();}catch(Exception e){}
        }
        else if(archivo.exists())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo ya existe.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más específico?

Comment: Como funciona es utilizado un jTextField de esta forma:

Comment: carpeta=new File(ruta,JDatos.getText());

Comment: pero al utilizar un JOptionPane no puedo extraer el texto para hacer lo mismo:                                                                                                            opp = (javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el nombre de la bd"));

        archivo= new File(ruta,"BASES.db");    
        carpeta=new File(ruta,opp);

Comment: ¿De que forma convierto mi objeto: File ruta=new File("/Users/brianreyes/FBD/"); para poder seguir utilizando la librería? java.io.File

Comment: ¿Estás en Windows? Yo podría la ruta completa: `File ruta= new File("C:/Users/brianreyes/FBD");`¿Tienes permiso para escribir en la carpeta de ese usuario?

Comment: Estoy utilizando OS X. Sí permisos los tengo para poder crear directorios, pero como comentaba con anterioridad si puedo hacer este procedimiento utilizando un JTextField con un de esta forma: carpeta=new File(ruta,JTextField.getText());

Comment: ¿Este sí te lo crea `archivo= new File(ruta,"BASES.db");`? ¿Qué escribes en el option pane? El nombre del archivo seguido de `/`? ¿Por qué no imprimes la excepción que te da?, podría indicar qué está ocurriendo...

Comment: Si así como indicas, el archivo si me lo crea, en el option pase solo ingreso el nombre del folder pero ya intente también ponerle diagonal y no lo crea.

Comment: La carpeta si la puedo crear si no especifico la ruta así: `carpeta=new File(opp);` y me la crea en en proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

He simplificado el sistema y reordenado un poco tu código. Probado en windows funciona bien.

Esta es la clase con el main

```
public class TestCrearDirectorio {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        new Xxx();
    }

} //class
```

Clase que hace el trabajo:

```
//imports
import java.io.File; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class Xxx extends JFrame {

    private File ruta = new File( "test/" );
    private File carpeta;
    private File archivo;

    private String opp;

    /**
     * Construct
     * 
     */
    public Xxx() {
        super( "Prueba crear directorio" ); //set tittle
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 300, 200 );

        //La siguiente llamada reemplaza a la que se produciría sobre 
        //el método lanzado por el evento, por ejemplo al pulsar un 
        //botón, para el ejemplo pongo solo la parte que interesa
        execute(); 
    }


    private void execute() {
        opp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Introduce el nombre de la bd" );

        archivo = new File( ruta, "BASES.db" );    
        carpeta = new File( ruta, opp );

        //Traza
        System.out.println( "archivo -> " + archivo );
        System.out.println( "carpeta -> " + carpeta );

        crearCarpeta();
        crearFichero();
    }

    private void crearCarpeta() {

        //La carpeta NO existe -> intenta crearla
        if ( ! carpeta.exists( )) {

            try {
                carpeta.mkdir();

            } catch (Exception e) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 
                    null, 
                    "Error creando carpeta."
                );
                System.err.println( e.toString( ));
            }

        //La carpeta YA existe
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 
                null, 
                "La carpeta ya existe." 
            );
        }
    }

    private void crearFichero() {
        //El archivo NO existe -> intenta crearlo
        if ( ! archivo.exists( )) {

            try {
                archivo.createNewFile();

            } catch( Exception e ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 
                    null, 
                    "Error creando archivo."
                );
                System.err.println( e.toString( ));
            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, 
                "El archivo ya existe."
            );
        }
    }

} //class
```

Lo que vi raro en tu código es el orden de anidado try-catch con el de los condicionales y que preguntas dos veces la misma condición en cada bloque. Primero, cuando tratas de crear la carpeta, todo esta dentro del try-catch, incluso la pregunta de si ya existe la carpeta. Para crear el fichero el try-cath incluye solo la creación del fichero. Con respecto a esto, como no pones nada en el catch, no estas recibiendo ninguna información sobre lo que falla dentro de estas estructuras, solo evitando que se lancen excepciones, así tu código falla en silencio, y has acabado aquí preguntando.
Luego los condicionales, tipo:

```
a es 1
si a es diferente de 1 hacer X
si a es igual a 1 hacer Z
```

podrías expresarlos así:

```
int a = 1;
if ( a != 1 ) {
   //hacer X
}
if ( a == 1 ) {
   //hacer Z
}
```

pero si usas el else, como solo hay dos posibles respuestas en este caso, o a valo 1 o no vale 1, sería:

```
int a = 1;
if ( a != 1 ) {
   //hacer X

} else {
   //hacer Z
}
```

Si no entra en el bloque del **if** (a no es 1) entra en el **else** (a es 1). Volver a preguntar esta de más y a más código más posibilidad de fallos, más consumo de recursos, código menos limpio, más díficil de mantener... vamos que es malo, como meterse de cabeza en una tinaja si estas sólo en casa.